# Visual Studio Shortcuts: Disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

*This has finally driven me completely mad.* Most of the Visual Studio specific keyboard shortcuts (meaning shortcuts like ctrl+c or ctrl+v are **not** included in this list) for both VS2010 and VS2013 haven't been working for me for the last two months, and I have no clue how/if I managed to disable them.

#### Examples of shortcuts that aren't working (by no means an inclusive list)

*Note that for all of the below I have confirmed that the expected shortcut combination **is** assigned to the action I'm trying to perform.*

- F12 to go to definition
- All debugging shortcuts
- F5 to start debugging

## What I've Tried So Far

- Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard → Reset
- Tools → Import and Export Settings → Reset all settings (*which seems to be the exact same thing as the first bullet point, but I'm desperate here*)
- Visual Studio restarts (multiple)
- Deleting .suo file
- Computer restarts (multiple)

#### Any suggestions for what else I can try to get these shortcuts to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't a Visual Studio issue at all. Apparently on my new keyboard **there is a 'F Lock' key that locks all the function buttons**...and I must have accidentally pressed it at one point. It just so happens that Visual Studio is the only program that I currently use that has so many function key hotkeys.